# ModuleNotFoundError in a virtual environment

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I'm getting started with virtual environments, and I'm having some sort of path issue.

First I create a virtual environment:

```
python -m venv conda-env
.\conda-env\Scripts\activate
```

(conda-env) shows up in the prompt.

Now I install a package:

```
pip install netcdf4
pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
cftime     1.1.3
netCDF4    1.5.3
numpy      1.19.0
pip        19.2.3
setuptools 41.2.0
```

Everything looks good. Now if i start a console and try to load the module, things go haywire:

```
jupyter console
In [1]: import netCDF4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9588a3d4fb24> in <module>
----> 1 import netCDF4

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'
```

If I run the console from the site-packages directory however, the following runs with no errors.

```
cd .\conda-env\Lib\site-packages\
jupyter console
import netCDF4
```

edit1:
If I install jupyter in my virtual environment, that fixes the problem.

```
pip install jupyter
```

I don't get it. Do I need to do this for every virtual environment?

edit2:
If I use python directly, instead of a jupyter console I don't get this problem. The code below works where test.py has the line import netCDF4.

```
python -m venv venv
./venv/Scripts/activate
pip install netCDF4
python test.py
```

edit 3
On a mac, pip install jupyter doesn't fix the problem. I'm very confused.

Comment: Yes you do. It is common to use a `requirements.txt` file that specifies your packages so you only need to make one call to pip like: `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This file is usually made part of the code and checked into source control. More advanced package management is also available in tools like `python-poetry`...although you don't typically need to learn about that until you are ready to publish packages to pypi.org or the like.

Comment: You seem to be mixing Anaconda and Python's own package manager `pip`. You should probably not do that.

Comment: Tha standard `venv` needs a dot bofor the `activate` command, like `. ./env/bin/activate`. The first dot is your shell's `source` command.

Answer (score 1):

I set the PYTHONPATH environment variable in the virtual environment to include the virtual environment site-packages path, for ex.

```
# Setting the PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/leo/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

This should pick up the packages you installed in your virtual environment with pip install.